# solr add document error

Tags: scala, solr, document

I am trying to load CSV file to solr doc, i am trying using scala. I am new to scala. For case class structure, if i pass one set of values it works fine. But if i want to want all read values from CSV, it gives an error. I am not sure how to do it in scala, any help greatly appreciated.

```
object BasicParseCsv {
  case class Person(id: String, name: String,age: String, addr: String )
  val schema = ArrayBuffer[Person]()


  def main(args: Array[String]) { 
    val master = args(0)
    val inputFile = args(1)
    val outputFile = args(2)
    val sc = new SparkContext(master, "BasicParseCsv", System.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) 
    val params = new ModifiableSolrParams  
    val Solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/person1") 

    //Preparing the Solr document
    val doc = new SolrInputDocument()

    val input = sc.textFile(inputFile)
    val result = input.map{ line =>
      val reader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(line));
      reader.readNext();
    }

    def getSolrDocument(person: Person): SolrInputDocument = {
      val document = new SolrInputDocument()
      document.addField("id",person.id)
      document.addField("name", person.name)
      document.addField("age",person.age)
      document.addField("addr", person.addr)
      document
    }

    def send(persons:List[Person]){
      persons.foreach(person=>Solr.add(getSolrDocument(person)))
      Solr.commit()
    }

    val people = result.map(x => Person(x(0), x(1),x(2),x(3)))

    val book1 = new Person("101","xxx","20","abcd") 

    send(List(book1)) 

    people.map(person => send(List(Person(person.id, person.name, person.age,person.addr))))

    System.out.println("Documents added")

  }
}
```

people.map(person => send(List(Person(person.id, person.name, person.age,person.addr))))   ==> gives error

val book1 = new Person("101","xxx","20","abcd")  ==> works fine

Update : I get below error
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
    at BasicParseCsv$.main(BasicParseCsv.scala:90)
    at BasicParseCsv.main(BasicParseCsv.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient, value: org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient@1dbd580)
    - field (class: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer, name: httpClient, type: interface org.apache.http.client.HttpClient)
    - object (class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer, org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer@17e0827)
    - field (class: BasicParseCsv$$anonfun$main$1, name: Solr$1, type: class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Updated the error, can you please help on that ?.